# Xcode 4.3.3 missing SenTestingKet.framework causes Undefined symbols "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_SenTestCase"

Tags: osx-lion, xcode4.3, sentestingkit

On my MAC mini [osx-snow-leopard](/questions/tagged/osx-snow-leopard) [xcode4.1](/questions/tagged/xcode4.1) my project can run SenTestingKit.framework tests.  Got a MACBook Pro with [osx-lion](/questions/tagged/osx-lion) 10.7.4 with [xcode4.3](/questions/tagged/xcode4.3).  For the same project I cannot run unit tests because SenTestingKit.framework is not to be found.  I copy [sentestingkit](/questions/tagged/sentestingkit) from the Mac mini to "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks".  Add to each target Framework Search Paths:
$(inherited)
"$(DEVELOPER_LIBRARY_DIR)/Frameworks"

This resolves to "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks".

I can add [sentestingkit](/questions/tagged/sentestingkit) to the project so it compiles.  I can't run Product > Test because of this link error [undefined-symbol](/questions/tagged/undefined-symbol):

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_SenTestCase", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_Field_MobileApplicationTests in Field_MobileApplicationTests.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SenTestCase", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_Field_MobileApplicationTests in Field_MobileApplicationTests.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem by using my class that want to be tested. I got this error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
"_OBJC_METACLASS_$_JsonDictParser", referenced from:
   _OBJC_METACLASS_$_MainData in MainData.o
   _OBJC_METACLASS_$_JsonObjectClass in JsonObjectClass.o
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_JsonDictParser", referenced from:
   _OBJC_CLASS_$_MainData in MainData.o
   _OBJC_CLASS_$_JsonObjectClass in JsonObjectClass.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I have created an object from my class that I want to test and forgot to tell the „Target Membership“. So I make sure I checked the test class.

E.g. I want to use `JsonDictParser` class for testing in my `JsonTestLogicTest` class. So I focus the `JsonDictParser.m` file, clicked the `File Inspector` at the right side on the main window, selected `Target Membership` and checked my class where my testcases are in `JsonTestLogicTest`.

Or open the `.xcodeproject` file in the Project Navigator, select the target with the test methods > Build Phases > Compile Sources and add the `.m` file which includes your classs that you want to test.

Comment: My error is it can't find SenTestCase which is in SenTestingKit.framework.  SenTestingKit.framework is in Link Binary with Libraries in Build Phases for the test target.